# How to solve Piecewise function in Reduce？

Tags: piecewise

Here I have a Piecewise Function:

```
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{53, 0 <= x < 100}, {4, 100 <= x < 102}, {71, 
   102 <= x < 140}, {29, 140 <= x < 184}, {12, 184 <= x < 190}, {8, 
   190 <= x < 191}, {28, 191 <= x < 252}, {72, 252 <= x < 293}, {80, 
   293 <= x < 313}, {15, 313 <= x < 323}, {23, 323 <= x < 355}, {7, 
   355 <= x < 359}, {10, 359 <= x < 364}, {86, 364 <= x < 373}, {38, 
   373 <= x < 459}}]
```

And I have a Reduce:

```
Reduce[(f[k] >= 53) && (0 <= k < 1807), k, Integers] // ToString
```

f[k] is the Piecewise Function above, How to write the code?
Thanks~

Comment: Square brackets are used for function arguments in Mathematica. You were missing a curly bracket in the Piecewise function definition, and also you were not assigning your Piecewise function to any variable. I edited your post to fix this.

Could you provide a bit more information please? What do you expect your code to do? I can run it just fine and I get an output from the Reduce[], but I do not know if this is correct or what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat improving your code, this can be done as follows.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{53, 0 <= x < 100}, {4, 100 <= x < 102}, {71, 
102 <= x < 140}, {29, 140 <= x < 184}, {12, 184 <= x < 190}, {8, 
190 <= x < 191}, {28, 191 <= x < 252}, {72, 252 <= x < 293}, {80, 
293 <= x < 313}, {15, 313 <= x < 323}, {23, 323 <= x < 355}, {7, 
355 <= x < 359}, {10, 359 <= x < 364}, {86, 364 <= x < 373}, {38, 
373 <= x < 459}}]
FullSimplify[Reduce[(f[k] >= 53) && (0 <= k < 1807), k, Integers], 
Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers] // ToString
```

> `"0 <= k <= 99 || 101 < k < 140 || 251 < k < 313 || 363 < k < 373"`

Comment: Thanks! It really helps me.

Comment: But if I want to solve the `Reduce` which involves two or more variables.How can I write the code?
Such as:
```
f[x_]=.....
g[x_]=...
FullSimplify[Reduce[(f[a]=g[b]) && (0< a < 100) && (0<b<200) , a , b, Integer.......]]
```
How can I write this? Could you tell me how to learn writing the code?